# Can't access phpmyadmin local

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have the following error while trying to connect to my local database with XAMPP. Could you please support me?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This is a PHP error, its the amount of time a php process is allowed to run before the process is terminated (timed out). You can increase the permitted execution time within PHP.INI however i would be looking more toward finding out the cause of the time out. You could increase the time out to say 2 or 3 minutes and run again, this might help identify the issue by throwing up some sort of error that means more.

Comment: Thank for replying. I have increased to 100 s the execution time and now I see the page but without any style loaded. I can't understand...

Comment: You may need to dig into your error logs for this one to see exactly what is failing and where.

Comment: I have used IE and now is working.

Comment: Thats great news. you may want to answer your own question then in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with another browser and it is working now. Maybe just a cache problem.